# Building .Net Code Analysis Tool

Tags: c#, reflection

I am looking to create .net code analysis tool based on custom rules.
i am going to use reflection to read entire code. Is there any way to read number of line consumed in class or method using reflection or any other assembly.

I am thinking to use some opensource tool so i can do modification in it but unable to find it on Google.

Suggestions are welcome!
thx

Comment: Reflection is for compiled assemblies. Whats wrong with `File.ReadAllText()`?

Comment: Reflection is used at runtime to inspect the compiled contents of a dll, not to inspect source code.  You probably need to look into [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) as a starting point, but this question itself is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I used reflection to count the number of methods , constructor in a class. i can understand whole thing we cannot achieve using reflection. i am thinking to right code through scratch but it will need more time. :(

Comment: Finding out anything about the source code requires reading the PDB file, just like the debugger does.  That's possible, the DIA SDK is the usual choice.  Maybe you are underestimating the effort to bring this to a good end.

Comment: DIA sdk is not present in my system. m looking for its link to download but it is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use reflection to "read the entire code".  How will you get any single statement?  Fundamentally you need a source code parser.

Maybe [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) is what you need.

Comment: Ira, I think Roslyn sdk is not available as i found it is in preview. its a built in feature under VS 2013+ versions . please confirm if m wrong?

Comment: I don't know in fact about its availability; I've never fetched it personally.  It is clear that many at SO have gotten some version (prerelease or not) and played with it,  The fact that it is hosted at GitHub (see link) suggests you can reach right out and download it.  Your alternative to "prerelease" is to go build your own stuff; Roslyn is so far beyond what you can reasonably dop in a year that you'd be crazy to do that.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to read number of line consumed in class or method using reflection or any other assembly.

This is not possible. The best you could do is to inspect the [`MethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody) for each [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo) which

> Provides access to the metadata and MSIL for the body of a method.

but lines of code is not something you can get. The number of lines is entirely a source code property and cannot be obtained through reflection.

Does

```
int x; x = 1; doSomethingWith(x);
```

count as one, two, or three lines? What about this:

```
int x;
x = 1;
doSomethingWith(x);
```

---

Lines of code is very rarely a useful metric - see, e.g.
"[*When, if ever, is “number of lines of code” a useful metric?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184071/1364007)"

---

As [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163) pointed out, you should probably look at Roslyn.

Comment: Is there any Code parser available ?? which can parse whole .cs page in terms of class , method , properties . hope it clear :(

Comment: Have a look at the [`System.CodeDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145034) namespaces. I've not used CodeDom at all so have no idea, but it looks like it it *might* be useful.

Comment: System.codedom is useful in creating dynamic class .

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're right. I was looking at [`CodeComProvider.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.parse) but actually that returns a [`CodeCompileUnit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codecompileunit) which doesn't help you.

Comment: i search  about Microsoft.CCi but we cannot used it in our application as it comes with Fxcop only. i can do it manually also but it will not give the exact result.